# Как в Node получить доступ к другому локальному диску?

Tags: node.js

Как в Node получить доступ к другому локальному диску? Что бы можно было просматривать директории и файлы? Насколько я понял модуль fs работает с диском где запущен проект.

Comment: А разве нельзя например, прочесть файл с другого диска вот так: `fs.readFileSync('D:/test.txt')`?

Comment: Работает. Спасибо.